# Error Creating Object tracking pointer with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, object-tracking

Please i need help
I am having an error when i try creating a pointer for object tracking with opencv

```
cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> tracker = cv::TrackerKCF::create();
```

The error says:

> TrackerKCF is not a member of CV.

I have checked the opencv documentation on objecttracking and i included the neccesary header. I am stuck.

The different header I included includes:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <iostream>
```

I have tried creating pointer for other object tracking algorithm according to OpenCV

```
cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> tracker = cv::TrackerMOSSE::create();
cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> tracker = cv::TrackerCSRT::create();
```

I received same Error

Comment: *" have checked the opencv documentation..."* Check the contents of the actual header that you've included. The documentation header may differ from the header you included, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: According to the OpenCV documentation, the header i need for object tracking is "#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>" i dont know if there is another header i am to include to make the code to compile.

Comment: But you've already included that header. So check the contents of that header in your system that you're actually including instead of checking the documentation header's content.

Comment: I have checked the actual file it doesn't seem to have the functionalities that i need. Please which header am i suppose to add to implement object tracking with OpenCV

Comment: As I suspected. Now the most probable cause is that you may not have the latest version of the files. Check the version in the header that you're actually including(which doesn't have the functionalities) and then compare it with the version used in the documentation header(which have the functionalities). If the version differ, then you would just need to update yours to the latest.

Comment: I am running 4.8 let me update to 4.9 and check again

Comment: I have updated my OpenCV to 4.9.0 which is the latest and am still getting same error

Comment: Have you checked the new header contents? See if it contains all the functionalities like `cv::TrackerKCF`. Basically, check if the new header's content matches with the contents of the documentation header. If not, you can file a bug at their official page.

Comment: I had to study tracking.hpp header file clearly i saw it supports some of the object tracking algorithm provided by OpenCV but not all. The object tracking algorithms specified by OpenCV are `cv::TrackerCSRT` `cv::TrackerDaSiamRPN` `cv::TrackerGOTURN` `cv::TrackerKCF` `cv::TrackerMIL` `cv::TrackerNano` `cv::TrackerVit` But the only algorithm it supports are `cv::TrackerMIL` `cv::TrackerGOTURN` `cv::TrackerDasiamRPN` `cv::TrackerNano` `cv::TrackerVit`

Comment: I will study the algorithms it supports to know that suits my work. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/tracking/tracking_legacy.hpp>

int main()
{
  auto tracker = cv::legacy::TrackerMOSSE::create();
  cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> tracker2 = cv::TrackerCSRT::create();
}
```

Note that `TrackerMOSSE` has been moved to "legacy" a long time ago (OpenCV 4.5.1).

Generally, everything is well documented, e.g. https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d2/da2/classcv_1_1TrackerCSRT.html, for CSRT, just chose the proper OpenCV version in the combo box and use the search widget.